# «Дугласова пихта» — с прописной или со строчной?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, названия

Как вы считаете, в художественной литературе нужно ли писать название дерева *дугласова пихта* с прописной буквы? Пример: *Они искали в парке Дугласову/дугласову пихту.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Считаю, что в художественной литературе прописную букву использовать не нужно.

*Средний возраст [дугласовой пихты](https://books.google.ee/books?id=OR0zDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT213&lpg=PT213&dq=%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%20%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BB%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B8%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82.&source=bl&ots=LpK7tqUa2g&sig=ACfU3U1waXE2GyAqevhub7v6Q_uvx70-qw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi5pviS4KPmAhXBl4sKHaZsASEQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%20%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BB%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B8%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82.&f=false) доходил до тысячи лет* (К. Паустовский).

*Между тем в лесу произрастали одни лишь хвойные деревья, в частности восхитительные дугласовы пихты с пышной, раскидистой кроной* (Ж. Верн).

**Голубой тетерев.** *Живет в лесах, где растет [дугласова пихта](https://books.google.ee/books?id=HFy1J81P3AgC&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%82%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=4Vq2A3Tfza&sig=ACfU3U1ADDcGiMdiMJZ4s4-r9VW4QDvmkg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjw4a2zhaTmAhVDpYsKHX6UAXEQ6AEwFXoECA0QAQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%82%D0%B0&f=false), так как зимой хвоя этой пихты — единственное пропитание для голубого тетерева* (Атлас животных и растений).

[Дугласова пихта](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/bse/85985/%D0%94%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) (БСЭ)
 [Нижняя часть дугласовой пихты]

**Дополнение** (по поводу "**Р**ентгеновых лучей")

Имена прилагательные, образованные от личных имен, **фамилий**, кличек при помощи суффиксов ***-ов*** (-ев) или *-ин* и обозначающие индивидуальную принадлежность, пишутся с прописной буквы, например:
*Рафаэлева Мадонна, Шекспировы трагедии, Гегелева «Логика», Далев словарь, Иваново детство, Танина книга, Муркины котята.*
Однако в составе фразеологических оборотов и в составных терминах прилагательные с ***-ов*** (-ев), -ин пишутся **со строчной буквы**, например:
*архимедов рычаг, вольтова дуга, бикфордов шнур, базедова болезнь, виттова пляска, **р**ентгеновы лучи.*

[Собственные имена людей, животных, мифологических существ и производные от них слова](http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=5821)

Answer (score 0):

Если это официальное название пихты, то везде пишется одинаково - со строчной буквы, но если в произведении персонаж имел в виду ту пихту, которую открыл  ботаник Д. Дуглас, т.е. употребил **Дугласову как притяжательное прилагательное** (пихта Дугласа - Дугласова пихта), то возможно. Как, например, лучи Рентгена - рентгеновские лучи - Рентгеновы лучи (которые открыл Рентген).